# Why click the button a second time, not the first time?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, timer, counter, addeventlistener

I wrote the following code to do a counter with each click.
But at the same time, nothing happens with the first click and the button starts counting from the second click.
Can you help me see what the problem is with this code and why the counter does not start the first time I click?

```
<button id="btn" class="btn" >click me</button>
<p>0</p>


<script>
    let count = 0;
    let number =document.querySelector("p");

const btn =document.getElementById("btn");

        btn.addEventListener("click" ,  ()=>
            number.innerHTML = count++
    )

</script>
```

Comment: You are increasing the value **after** you set it. Use `++count`.

Answer (score 1):

`count++` returns the value before adding 1. Split it into two lines:

```js
let count = 0;
let number = document.querySelector("p");

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count++;
  number.innerHTML = count;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn" class="btn">click me</button>
<p>0</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

As someone already mentioned, the post-increment operator (`count++`) increments the value after evaluating it (hence the *post*)

One option would be to use the pre-increment operator (`++count`) instead, which evaluates the variable after incrementing it.

```js
let count = 0;
const number = document.querySelector("p");

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => number.innerHTML = ++count);
```

```html
<button id="btn" class="btn">click me</button>
<p>0</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment the value of count first then assign it to (`number.innerHTML`). Use pre-increment operator (`++count`)